# returning value item (not text item) in combobox.text [wpf C#]

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have created a custom class `ComboboxItem` that takes `Text/Value` and a function to return a string.

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
     public string Text { get; set; }
     public object Value { get; set; }

     public override string ToString()
     {
        return Text;
     }
}
```

I populate the item and added it to a `ComboBox`.

```
ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
item.Text = result.CODEALIAS + " | " + result.DESCRIPTION;
item.Value = result.CODEALIAS;
comboBox.Items.Add(item);
```

and now the `ComboBox` shows both the `codealias + description` in each item. what I'm trying to do is just return the `codealias` in the content of the box once the user selects an item instead of the  whole Text

[image]

I tried the following on `SelectionChanged` of `ComboBox`.

```
comboBox.Text = (comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value.ToString();
```

And

```
comboBox.SelectedItem = (comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value.ToString();
```

and the program just crashes with this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I put a `BreakPoint` and it gets the value it just doesn't set it. Any ideas how to do this?

Item `datacontext` is set to a `ViewSource` since I need to load the initial value from a table. here's the XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged"  DataContext="{StaticResource myTableViewSource}" Text="{Binding myField}" shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" Canvas.Left="58" Canvas.Top="192" Width="120"/>
```

Comment: 'the program just crashes' - any clues as to the nature of the crash? Do you receive an exception message? Blue screen? Bad fires?

Comment: Yeah sorry, added more info. I know the error (object reference not set to an instance of an object) basically means its missing 'new', but it gets the value which is why I dont think thats causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly the smoothest UI experience, but you can swap the DisplayMemberPath between Text and Value when the ComboBox's DropDown is opened/closed. That just about meets your criteria.

XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="myComboBox" DropDownOpened="myComboBox_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="myComboBox_DropDownClosed" />
```

Codebehind

```
private void myComboBox_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Text";
}

private void myComboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
}
```

Comment: Hahaha, hey it works. thanks for your help. Youre awesome

Answer (score 1):

You should use WPF in a natural way, i.e. use [DataTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate(v=vs.100).aspx) to show what you want :

Code:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dataContext = new[]
            {
                new MyData
                {
                    Text = "a happy smiley",
                    Value = ":)"
                },
                new MyData
                {
                    Text = "a sad smiley",
                    Value = ":("
                }
            };
            DataContext = dataContext;
        }
    }

    internal class MyData
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="wpfApplication1:MyData">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didnt go this route since I have the field binded with a dataset viewsource. so I couldnt change the datacontext. ill add the XAML, thats my mistake. thanks for your reply.